# ValueError at /post/politics Field 'id' expected a number but got 'politics'

Tags: python, django

I have a template posts.html

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% block posts %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="cardpost">
        <h1>{{posts.title}}</h1>
        <h5>{{posts.created_at}}</h5>
        <div class="fs-4">{{posts.body | safe}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

posts.html extends base2.html, because I want the posts.html to have nav bar functionality

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="guestposting">Guest Posting</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href=""><span>Categories</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down dropdown-indicator"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="tech">Tech</a></li>
              <li><a href="bizconomics">Bizconomics</a></li>
              <li><a href="politics">Politics</a></li>
              <li><a href="religion">Religion</a></li>
              <li><a href="sports">Sports</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contactform">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

above is a section of the nav bar which is on base2.html, and also on the index.html. It works perfectly in the index.html. But when the user is on the posts.html-> path('post/str:pk', views.post, name='post') and they click politics category for instance, I get this error:

ValueError at /post/politics
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'politics'.

Here are my url routes

```
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('post/<str:pk>', views.post, name='post'),
    path('politicalpost/<str:pk>', views.politicalpost, name='politicalpost'),
    path('bizconomicspost/<str:pk>', views.bizconomicspost, name='bizconomicspost'),
    path('techpost/<str:pk>', views.techpost, name='techpost'),
    path('sportspost/<str:pk>', views.sportspost, name='sportspost'),
    path('religionpost/<str:pk>', views.religionpost, name='religionpost'),
    path('subscribe', views.subscribe, name ='subscribe'),
    path('contactform', views.contactform, name='contactform'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('guestposting', views.guestposting, name='guestposting'),
    path('bizconomics', views.bizconomics, name='bizconomics'),


   #These are the caregory urls
 
    path('tech', views.tech, name='tech'),
    path('sports', views.sports, name='sports'),
    path('politics', views.politics, name='politics'),
    path('religion', views.religion, name='religion'),
    path('culture', views.culture, name='culture'),
    path('culturepost/<str:pk>', views.culturepost, name='culturepost'),
```

So how can I make it possible such that when a user clicks on the politics category,  they are redirected from the posts.html to the politics page->path('politics', views.politics, name='politics'),

My views.py

```
def index(request):
    politics = Politics.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    trendingposts = Trending.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    religions = Religion.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    sliders = Heroslider.objects.all()
    return render(request,
    'index.html',
    {'politics':politics, 'posts':posts,'trendingposts':trendingposts,'religions':religions, 'sliders':sliders})


def politics(request):
    politics = Politics.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Politics/politics.html', {'politics':politics})

def post(request, pk):
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'posts.html', {'posts':posts})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try changing it:

```
<li><a href="politics">Politics</a></li>
```

With:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'politics' %}">Politics</a></li>
```